# Checking when an object is dragged over another object

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-event

I have simple example: [image: screenshot]

- 1 draggable object (red ball)
- 7 objects (rectangles)

I want to drag ball's object over rectangle's objects and when ball is over some rectangle, rectangle should hover. Is there some events which I can use? I know that I can use method `forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside | UIControlEventTouchDragInside` and assign it to the ball instance but in this case I will have to iterate through all rectangles and check if ball is over someone of them. Rather, I think of the solution, in which the rectangle itself will know that the object is on it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to look to:
CGRectContainsRect and CGRectContainsPoint
[CGGeometry reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: I know about this methods but as I said before I will have to iterate over each rectangle in that case. Is there any event in Cocoa that can be connected to the square object and triggered when the ball's object is on it?

Comment: You can create your own object and create a delegate method to trigger your own event